# MySQL ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint when I'm trying to create a table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I tried looking up the reasons why it's failing but I can't find the different data types issues mentioned in the solutions in my tables.

I'm getting the error when I'm trying to run the following:

```
comments (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id varchar(10) NOT NULL,
blog_id int NOT NULL,
comment varchar(150) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user_details(id),
FOREIGN KEY(blog_id) REFERENCES blog(id));
```

existing data bases for primary keys:

```
user_details (id varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
name varchar(70) NOT NULL, 
email varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
salt varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
masked_password varchar(40) NOT NULL,
is_active varchar(10) DEFAULT 'False');
```

```
blog (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
category_id int NOT NULL,
title varchar(240) NOT NULL,
body longtext NOT NULL,                
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES blog_catagories(id));
```

Let me know where I'm going wrong

Comment: Please don't tag DBMS that have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: sorry @Larnu I'll keep that in mind from the next time

Comment: You don't have Primary key defined on user_details table

Comment: Thanks a lot , that was the issue.